# Recursively parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I have a large JSON object that I created with Python, and I'm needing to display the information on a webpage now. My problem is the size of it; there are nested arrays and objects within, and it is several layers deep at points. I wrote an extremely inelegant (and buggy) JavaScript function to pull the data out, but this seems like a recursive problem to me, and I unfortunately am not used to thinking like that (yet).

Does anyone know of a good solution to <strike>parsing</strike> reading such an object? My goal here is to really read this somewhat dynamically, since I'm going to have to do this many more times (and each time the object will be different, but with more or less the same structure). **The goal is to take this information and show it meaningfully on a web page.**

Let me know if I can elaborate further.

Edit: Here's the object. I was away from my computer when I posted this, plus it's rather large. Parts of it that might be sensitive I've pulled out. And I'm using the JSON2 to parse this into something other than a string. It's just the sized and nestiness that's giving me a problem.

`{
    "Loop300": [
        {
            "Loop310": [
                {
                    "N1": {
                        "idCode": "0400", 
                        "idQual": "ZZ", 
                        "name": "REDACTED", 
                        "entIdCode": "SF"
                    }, 
                    "N3": [
                        {
                            "address1": "REDACTED", 
                            "address2": "REDACTED"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "G61": [
                        {
                            "contactFunctionCode": "CN", 
                            "commNumber": "REDACTED", 
                            "commNumQualifier": "TE", 
                            "name": "shipping"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "N4": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "L11": [], 
            "S5": {
                "stopReasonCode": "LD", 
                "stopSeqNum": "1"
            }, 
            "Loop350": [
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "161", 
                        "poNum": "ASDF", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "THING", 
                        "quantity": "6"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "1", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "104", 
                        "poNum": "ZXMO", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "STUFF", 
                        "quantity": "6"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "2", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "1833", 
                        "poNum": "ASDF", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "THEBLOB", 
                        "quantity": "40"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "3", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "229", 
                        "poNum": "FDSA", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "BATMAN", 
                        "quantity": "6"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "4", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "AT5": [], 
            "G62": [
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "10"
                }, 
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "38"
                }
            ], 
            "NTE": [
                {
                    "refCode": "OTH", 
                    "desc": "No Touch"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Loop310": [
                {
                    "N1": {
                        "idCode": "9998000006", 
                        "idQual": "ZZ", 
                        "name": "REDACTED", 
                        "entIdCode": "SF"
                    }, 
                    "N3": [
                        {
                            "address1": "REDACTED"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "G61": [
                        {
                            "contactFunctionCode": "CN", 
                            "commNumber": "REDACTED", 
                            "commNumQualifier": "TE", 
                            "name": "REDACTED"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "N4": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "L11": [], 
            "S5": {
                "stopReasonCode": "LD", 
                "stopSeqNum": "2"
            }, 
            "Loop350": [
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "poNum": "QWERTY", 
                        "refID": "ASDF", 
                        "unitMeasure": "PL", 
                        "quantity": "1"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "1", 
                                "desc": "PORT"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "AT5": [], 
            "G62": [
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "10"
                }, 
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "38"
                }
            ], 
            "NTE": [
                {
                    "refCode": "OTH", 
                    "desc": "Driver Count Required"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Loop310": [
                {
                    "N1": {
                        "idCode": "9998000070", 
                        "idQual": "ZZ", 
                        "name": "PLACE", 
                        "entIdCode": "ST"
                    }, 
                    "N3": [
                        {
                            "address1": "PLACE"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "G61": [
                        {
                            "contactFunctionCode": "CN", 
                            "commNumber": "XXXXXXXXXX", 
                            "commNumQualifier": "TE", 
                            "name": "X"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "N4": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "L11": [], 
            "S5": {
                "stopReasonCode": "UL", 
                "stopSeqNum": "3"
            }, 
            "Loop350": [
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "poNum": "JOE", 
                        "refID": "SUPERMAN", 
                        "unitMeasure": "PL", 
                        "quantity": "1"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "1", 
                                "desc": "PORT"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "AT5": [], 
            "G62": [
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "68"
                }, 
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "54"
                }
            ], 
            "NTE": [
                {
                    "refCode": "OTH", 
                    "desc": "No Touch"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Loop310": [
                {
                    "N1": {
                        "idCode": "0000403803", 
                        "idQual": "ZZ", 
                        "name": "REDACTED", 
                        "entIdCode": "ST"
                    }, 
                    "N3": [
                        {
                            "address1": "REDACTED"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "G61": [
                        {
                            "contactFunctionCode": "CN", 
                            "commNumber": "0000000000", 
                            "commNumQualifier": "TE", 
                            "name": "REDACTED"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "N4": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "L11": [
                {
                    "qualifier": "DO", 
                    "refID": "THETHING"
                }
            ], 
            "S5": {
                "stopReasonCode": "UL", 
                "stopSeqNum": "4"
            }, 
            "Loop350": [
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "161", 
                        "poNum": "UIP", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "JACK", 
                        "quantity": "6"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "1", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "104", 
                        "poNum": "JKLM", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "SUSAN", 
                        "quantity": "6"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "2", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "1833", 
                        "poNum": "ASDF", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "JOE", 
                        "quantity": "40"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "3", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "LAD": [], 
                    "OID": {
                        "weight": "229", 
                        "poNum": "AAAA", 
                        "weightCode": "L", 
                        "unitMeasure": "CA", 
                        "refID": "ASDF", 
                        "quantity": "6"
                    }, 
                    "Loop360": [
                        {
                            "Loop365": [], 
                            "L5": {
                                "lineNum": "4", 
                                "desc": "STUFF"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "AT5": [], 
            "G62": [
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "68"
                }, 
                {
                    "date": "20100817", 
                    "datequalifier": "54"
                }
            ], 
            "NTE": [
                {
                    "refCode": "OTH", 
                    "desc": "Driver Assist Required"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "SE": {
        "numSegments": "70", 
        "controlNum": "0002"
    }, 
    "Loop100BT": [], 
    "L11": [
        {
            "qualifier": "VD", 
            "refID": "SALLY"
        }, 
        {
            "qualifier": "SI", 
            "refID": "MARK"
        }, 
        {
            "qualifier": "CR", 
            "refID": "JOE"
        }, 
        {
            "qualifier": "RB", 
            "refID": "USD"
        }, 
        {
            "qualifier": "TH", 
            "refID": "REDACTED"
        }
    ], 
    "PLD": [], 
    "L3": {
        "weight": "2328", 
        "advances": "0", 
        "rateQual": "FR", 
        "charge": "05", 
        "freightRate": "", 
        "weightQual": "G", 
        "quantity": "59"
    }, 
    "B2": {
        "ordernum": "12345", 
        "paymethod": "PP", 
        "scac": "XXXX"
    }, 
    "Loop100VI": [
        {
            "N1": {
                "name": "REDACTED", 
                "entIdCode": "AA"
            }, 
            "G61": [
                {
                    "contactFunctionCode": "CN", 
                    "commNumber": "REDACTED", 
                    "contactReference": "0563", 
                    "commNumQualifier": "TE", 
                    "name": "REDACTED"
                }, 
                {
                    "contactFunctionCode": "IC", 
                    "commNumber": "REDACTED", 
                    "commNumQualifier": "EM", 
                    "name": "REDACTED"
                }, 
                {
                    "contactFunctionCode": "ZZ", 
                    "name": "REDACTED"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "G62": [
        {
            "date": "20100827", 
            "timequalifier": "1", 
            "datequalifier": "64", 
            "time": "1302"
        }
    ], 
    "Loop100CB": [], 
    "NTE": [
        {
            "refCode": "ZZZ", 
            "desc": "26"
        }, 
        {
            "refCode": "OTH", 
            "desc": "No Touch"
        }, 
        {
            "refCode": "OTH", 
            "desc": "Driver Count Required"
        }, 
        {
            "refCode": "OTH", 
            "desc": "No Touch"
        }, 
        {
            "refCode": "OTH", 
            "desc": "Driver Assist Required"
        }
    ], 
    "B2A": {
        "purpose": "00"
    }, 
    "N7": [
        {
            "equipLength": "4800", 
            "equipHeight": "0", 
            "weight": "2328", 
            "equipWidth": "0", 
            "equipNum": "ZZZZ", 
            "equipType": "TV", 
            "weightQual": "G"
        }
    ]
}`

Thanks,
T.J.

Comment: Hey @tjsimmons, can you show us the structure of your JSON?

Comment: `Does anyone know of a good solution to parsing such an object?` Showing *the object* might help.

Comment: Doesn't `JSON.parse()` work?

Comment: only on new browsers. if you wish to depend on JSON you *must* include json2.js.

Comment: Ask before killing, and search before doing :)

Comment: Killed before I asked, haha. The post has been updated.

Comment: wow dude.. thats some json only a mother could love....

Comment: You should have seen what it looked like before I parsed it with Python. It's been a crazy week and this is the last part of it.

Comment: I shudder to think what your non-recursive parser looked like.

Comment: It's scary. And only partially worked - I had a bug in it that skipped over some sections.

Answer (score 10):

do your mean something like this?

```
function iterateAttributesAndFormHTMLLabels(o){
    var s = '';
    for(var a in o){
        if (typeof o[a] == 'object'){
            s+='<label><font color=green>'+a+':</font></label><br />';
            s+=iterateAttributesAndFormHTMLLabels(o[a]);
        }else{
            s+='<label>'+a+': <font color=blue>'+o[a]+'</font></label><br />';
        }//end if
    }//end for
    return s;
}//end function

data = {...};

var html = iterateAttributesAndFormHTMLLabels(data);
```

No idea if it works in all browsers, does in Chrome and firefox

cheers,
Ian

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I searched this simple solution for 2 days :)

Answer (score 7):

I can appreciate that you are trying to make your question more specific but there is simply not enough information.

The json presented is extremely abstract, most of the keys infer little or no context to the meaning of the data, the structure is quite expansive making the effort to glean the meaning problematic.

'Meaningful' is an ambiguous, relative and subjective term.

Please try to condense and clarify your data exemplar and be more specific in how you would propose to present it and you will have more luck getting answers and guidance relevant to your requirements.

Cheers

---

<sub>this is my original answer to the question as originally stated</sub>

Include https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js in your page. If the browser does not have native JSON, it will fill in.

then

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(myjsonstring);
```

rolling your own is just a silly thing to do.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I meant parse as in the generic "do something meaningful". I used json2.js to change the string into what I posted above.

Comment: @tjs then your next step would be strike the term 'parse' and replace it with a description of what this useful thing you want to do...

Comment: Done and done. It was quite late when I posted this last night and I'd been staring at it for a while. I added what I actually want to do with the information into the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [JQuery's `parseJSON()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

JQuery's implementation will use the browser's built-in `JSON.parse()` function, if it exists, and if not, it'll fall back to a pure javascript implementation.

---

[edit] as pointed out by @Sky, the jQuery implementation is substantially simpler than the reference implementation provided by [json.org](http://json.org/), and this could present some issues in cases where the source of your JSON isn't necessarily trusted.

My experience is that jQuery's parser *will* correctly consume *any valid JSON* (if anyone can show otherwise, I would very much like to see it).  The problem is that it will *also* consume a number of things that *aren't* JSON--namely, it will consume (and evaluate) any valid javascript expression.  Since expressions could contain function calls, this would present a security issue if your JSON comes from an un-trusted source.

However, if the source of your JSON is trusted (eg. your own server), then I can see no reason to incur the extra overhead (both code size, and performance) of the stricter implementation.  This is *especially* true if you're already including the jQuery core for other reasons (which you may or may not be).

Of course, all of this is a fairly pedantic discussion, since both implementations fall back to the browser built-in if it exists -- which it does in all modern browsers.  My point is merely that the jQuery implementation has its strengths, and is a perfectly valid choice in many scenarios.  In other situations, you may be better served by the reference implementation from [json.org](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: i would be hard pressed to cite a less capable json implementation that that of jquery's.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?  Many many sites and systems use jQuery's json parser every day.  Anyone who uses the jQuery ajax functions is implicitly using the jQuery json implementation.

Comment: @Sky: I'd be interested as well. JSON is not exactly a complicated format, I'd even call it *hard* to implement it incorrectly or incompletely.

Comment: @tom et al - jquery will use native json, if present, if not it falls back on a very naive implementation that is not safe and often errors out processing perfectly valid json. just because many people buy what they are sold without question, i.e. 'jquery iz da bomb, duedz', does not confer capability to the code. i am not throwing shade on jquery or those who use it, i do regularly, but when i am writing applications i need code i can count on, thus i back up native implementations with the code that they were base on, json2.js

Comment: @tom et al - additionally, there are many documented inconsistencies and bugs in the current native json implementations for which I modify the polite nature of json2.js to overwrite native stringify and/or parse for the problematic user agents.

Comment: @Sky: Can you give an example of valid JSON that jQuery fails to parse? I'm not in the "jQuery iz da bomb" camp at all, let alone a fan of "throw jQuery at every problem", but I really have a hard time imaginating JSON that is hard to parse or ambiguous and calls for an advanced parser.

Comment: @tom - sorry, i don't have the code on hand, as i resolved the issues and moved on. i have presented my personal experience and you can find examples on the intertubes. there are many subtle issues related to json, parsing thereof and most especially security that makes parsing of json anything but trivial. I suggest that you simply click on the json2.js link i provide and read through crockford's explanation of each step of a capable parsing process. cheers.

Comment: @Sky- I am certainly not one who assumes that capability is conferred by merely being associated with a widely accepted and heavily used 3rd-party package.  But neither am I a person who would abandon an approach that has worked well for me many, many times, simply because someone asserts that it's ineffective, incapable or naive.  Of course you're entitled to your opinion, and I'm sure it's supported by your experience; but if it's worth a down-vote, it's also worth providing some concrete examples and reasoning to back it up.  IMHO-both ways are acceptable-I'll elaborate in the next comment.

Comment: I'll grant that the reference implementation at json.org *is* stricter and more feature-full than jQuery's.  That said, I have yet to find valid JSON that wouldn't parse with jQuery's parser.  If your JSON comes from an untrusted source then--by all means--please avoid using jQuery's parser. jQuery will accept (and execute) many valid js expressions that aren't valid JSON at all. These wouldn't be accepted by the json.org parser.  That said - if your JSON comes from a trusted source (and esp. if you're already using jquery for other stuff), then I see no harm in using jQuery's impl.

Comment: @lee - what i am saying is that in more than one commercial project i have had to abandon jquery for json processing because it was consistently unable to parse a particular shape of valid json emitted by WCF without crashing. and i am not the only one. my experience tells me that if something fails once, beware, if it fails twice, find another solution and stick to it. in the interest of edification i will see if i can come up with some examples.

Comment: @Sky - Thanks for the info.  If you can dig up any examples I'd definitely be interested to see them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JS templating engine to transform your JSON to a humanly readable HTML.

Here is an example of recursion with the PURE templating lib: http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/recursion-example/

The template here is quite generic, using a `UL/LI` combination.

Or if you want to render it for instance in a textbox you can use `JSON.stringify`:

```
document.getElementById('theTextBox').value = JSON.stringify(theJson, null, 2);
```

The call above to `stringify` will indent the JSON with 2 spaces.