# Complex JSON string Parsing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

This is my sample JSON file , which im trying to parse and read the values ....

```
C = {{
    "Travel": {
        "ServiceProvider": {
            "Name": "SRS",
            "Rating": "3 stars",
            "Rates": "Nominal",
            "Features": {
                "OnlineBooking": "Yes",
                "SMS_Ticket": "No"
            },
            "UserDetails": {
                "Name": "Jack",
                "Age": "33",
                "Gender": "Male"
            }
        },
        "BusProvider": {
            "Name": "SRS",
            "Rating": "3 stars",
            "Rates": "Nominal",
            "Features": {
                "OnlineBooking": "Yes",
                "SMS_Ticket": "No"
            },
            "UserDetails": {
                "Name": "Jack",
                "Age": "33",
                "Gender": "Male"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to JS , and i need to access the nested elements in a generic fashion.

Im not able to extract the details properly. Im getting stuck accessing nested the child elements.

1. The problem for me is that i wont always know the names of the "key's' to acess them , the JSON will be dynamic , hence i need a generic mechanism to acess the nested child elements. The Nesting can go upto 3 -4 levels.
2. what notation do we use to access the key / value pairs when the nesting is deep.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are you planning to show these elements?by alert?

Comment: I actually need to build an object out of these JSON. I have added the alert just for example sake ..

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104321/recursively-parsing-json

Comment: I don't get it, after `var Data = JSON.parse(c);` Data will contain everything easly accessible (e.g. `Data.Travel.BusProvider.Name === 'SRS'`). Why would you need another parse method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Complex JSON in JS or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457366/parsing-complex-json-in-js-or-jquery) -- you already asked this question and it was closed as duplicate. In that other question it is explained how you can iterate over an object using `for...in`. I will update it to mention recursion as well though.

Comment: @ Yoshi : Yes i understand that once it is parsed , everything will be available. But my problem is not with parsing , but with accessing. And also as i mentioned , i wont always know the name of the element to access it as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

ater desirializing your object you can do this

```
var resultJSON = '{"name":"ricardo","age":"23"}';
var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    //display the key 
    alert(k + ' is the key)
}
```

you can do it using recursively offcourse like this - [Link Here](https://rvieiraweb.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/jquery-building-list-with-json-object/) 
the way is the same just adapt to your example

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic access you can use brackets notation i.e. `var json = {nonKnown: 1};` now you can access it like that:
var unknowPropertyName = "nonKnown";
var value = json[unknownPropertyName];

But if you can not even define dynamically name of the property, then you should use

```
for(variableName in json){
  if(json.hasOwnProperty(variableName)){
    console.log(variableName);
  }
}
```

You should get the basic idea from this. Good luck